# Error while executing 'select convert' on hive table

Tags: sql, hiveql

I want to execute this sql query on a hive table:

```
select * from sampleDB.sampleTable 
  where sampleDate>=(select convert(DATE, dateadd(MONTH,-6,getdate())));
```

But I am getting this error: `Error while compiling statement: FAILED: parse exception line 1:64 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'convert' '(' in expression specification (state=42000,code=40000)`

Can someone help me understand how this can be achieved? Basically I want to filter on date say 6 months from current date.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive do not supports only >= in [sub query](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Subqueries+in+SELECT) it support only below type of sub query

1. Scalar subqueries
2. IN subqueries
3. EXISTS subqueries

you can achieve the same with da[enter link description here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)teformate

```
select * from sampleDB.sampleTable 
  where sampleDate>= date_format(current_date - interval '7' day,'%Y-%m-%d') ;
```

Comment: Thanks @sandeepjust to know a bit, when i run `select date_format(current_date - interval '18' month,'YYYY-MM-DD');` i get the output as `2017-01-18`. basically for month wise selection it works fine... but for day: `select date_format(current_date - interval '6' day,'YYYY-MM-DD');` it gives `2018-07-193` even for year the selection is very wierd... just trying to understand how this is working

Comment: not sure why but when i just rewrite as `YYYY-MM-dd` den it works fine, instead of `YYYY-MM-DD`!

Comment: it is date_format function parm these we have to twice according  to our need more you can find ..http://hadooptutorial.info/hive-date-functions/